# Does every infinite recursive language contain an infinite regular subset?

Tags: computability, regular-languages

My intuition is telling me that this is not the case. But I am having trouble formulating a proof for this.How do I prove it ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: @Raphael  Sorry. No memory. I did not remember that it had been answered previously, and what's worse, by myself. Actually I had to think again to get the answer. Well ... so it goes. But this question raises another question for meta.

Comment: I'm sorry if this was a duplicate but I didn't thought of searching what subsets a language can have. I had thought of giving a counter example and using the pumping lemma but I could't think of a language with the above criteria. All I wanted was a hint. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the language $L= \{a^{2^p}\mid p\geq 1\}$.

> It is easy to show with the pumping lemma that it contains no infinite regular subset.

Try to prove it is a counter-example.

> The reason is that the pumping lemma requires, for infinite regular sets, that some infinite sequence of strings in the language grows linearly in size. But the language $L$ contains no such sequence because its strings grow exponentially. Hence it cannot contain an infinite regular subset.